# Mark text with mvim

Tags: macos, vim

I'm using mvim on my Mac OS X 10.7.

How can I mark text to do copy, paste, delete, etc operations? From gvim on Windows I'm used to use the shift key for this, but that doesn't work on the Mac.

Comment: I'm pretty sure marking by shift isn't a default vim command. For the rest of the question - why not read the manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows, GVim uses a special script designed to make it easier to use. The flip side is that you can go a (not very) long way without learning Vim properly.

There are two basic ways to "yank", "put" and "delete" some arbitrary text in Vim:

- **Using visual selection**

  This works more or less like what you are used to, well, everywhere: you select a portion of text with visual feedback then act on it.

  1. In *normal* mode, place your cursor at one end of the text you want to do something with.
  2. Enter *visual* mode with `v`.
  3. Move the cursor to the the other end.
  4. Hit `y` to copy the selected text, `d` to delete it, `c` to delete it and enter *insert* mode, `P` to replace it with the content of the default register.
  5. Done.

  `v` has two very useful variants: `V` to enter *visual line* mode and `<C-v>` to enter *visual block* mode.

  Here is an example with the sequence `v<left><left>…<left><left>y` (there are more efficient ways, of course):

  [image: yanking a visual selection]

  See `:help visual-mode`.
- **Using motions and text-objects**

  This one is very different from the norm and also extremely efficient.

  1. In *normal* mode, place your cursor at one end of the text you want to do something with. Some text-objects/motions don't require that.
  2. Hit `y` (or `d` or `c`).
  3. Define a range or target on which to act with `i(` or `f"`.
  4. Done.

  Here is an example with this sequence `dta`:

  [image: deleting with a motion]

  See `:help motion.txt`.

Of course, it works the same on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X and, of course, you can mix and match these two methods to suit your needs.

The "yanking" example could be achieved with `vbbby`, `v4by`, `v2Fiy`, `v?ip<esc>y`, `y2Fi`, etc. depending on the number of words/lines you are dealing with and the "deleting" example could be achieved with `v<right><right>…<right><right>d`, `vll…lld`, `vwwwhd`, `vfad`, etc.